# Do comment threads that get moved to chat actually live on?

Tags: discussion, comment-to-chat-migration

Is there any data on how often people actually continue comment threads in chat after their comments get nuked?

In my experience of comment threads that get moved to chat, the thread just dies, but this is purely anecdotal.

Comment: Occasionally these comment threads get moved to chat even though there aren't enough messages for the system to consider the room "worth retaining" (at least 16), which leads to these rooms getting deleted and the former comments getting lost from public view.

Comment: I don't know if I would have an easy way of putting together any kind of meaningful metrics on this, and the most important thing that won't be in the data anyway is "why did any _specific_ conversation die when it got moved to chat." Also anecdotal but I find that many people start the chat room just because the prompt to do so showed up, so at least some of the time a room gets opened even though there is nothing further to discuss. Admittedly, on several occasions, I have bailed on conversations because the invite to chat has always felt like "come be my personal consultant over there."

Comment: @AaronBertrand the "why it dies when moved" is easy, because people don't get any notification. I was surprised to get notification when someone pinged me in such moved conversation, I was sure the comments were just deleted when the notifications I had were gone, and it was on a site I don't frequent, so didn't think to go directly to the post and check it out.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I’m fairly certain I’ve had a notification about it before, but on a busy comment thread I don’t know if everyone should get a ping when one person decided to open a room. Anyway I don’t think the answer is that simple, even just this one person has had multiple very different motivations for not engaging even when I knew very well that the room had been created.